# Collaboration document.referrer with a split for the host

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code to display the url traffic with modifications split in the domain.

My code:

```
<div class="TEST"></div>
<script>
function extDom(url) {
    var domain;
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
        domain = url.split('/')[2]
    } else {
        domain = url.split('/')[0]
    }
    domain = domain.split(':')[0];
    return domain
}

var okejos = jQuery.noConflict();
var okezip = decodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
var myURI = extDom(okezip);
if ((myURI == "") || (myURI == "google.co.id") || (myURI == "google.com")) {} 
else {
    okejos(".TEST").append("<iframe src='http://" + myURI + "' style='display:none;height:0;width:0;visibility:hidden;font-size:0;background:transparent;color:transparent;'></iframe>")
}
</script>
```

This code works for:
If the source links from `google.com/search/keyword` and `google.co.id/search/keyword`
Then the source link in print is `google.com` and `google.co.id`

Well, can I just print `Google` without any `.com` or `co.id`?

Comment: `alert("google.co.id".substring(0,"google.co.id".indexOf(".")))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.substring()` and `.indexOf()` as shown :-

```js
var temp = "google.co.id";
alert(temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf(".")));
```

**Note :-** If you want first letter capitalize then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript) SO post.

Comment: As far I understand for code use `myURI.substring(0,myURI.indexOf(".")) `.

Comment: @pemulabanget..still facing problem?